# adding a calculated (count) field to firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app to keep track of `locations` and `checkins`. Users check in during the day to different locations, and I want to keep a realtime overview over the number of users in each location.

I save check-in's in one collection and the locations in another.

I want to add a field to the location object that is calculated based on how many users are currently checked in to the location. Is there a way to do this on the db side, or would I have to create a new query for each of the locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

1. Install Cloud Functions and connect with your project
2. Add a onCreate trigger when someone checks in. This method should be called whenever a person adds data to, for example, your location (user checks in)
3. Increase the counter with the transaction

Comment: I'm struggling with the concept of the triggers. What I don't understand is where to put the trigger function, so that firestore knows always to call that function, when any update happens to the db. I mean, won't I have to ping the url of the function if I put it up as a cloud function?

Comment: Have you installed Node and did setup Cloud Functions? You add a write trigger and when a person writes to that URL you specified, the cloud function will fire.